# Running tests with cucumber-junit-platform-engine and Selenium WebDriver opens too many threads

Tags: spring, selenium, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-junit

I have tried to configure an existing Maven project to run using cucumber-junit-platform-engine.

*I have used [this](https://github.com/mpkorstanje/cucumber-spring-boot-parallel) repo as inspiration.*

I added the Maven dependencies needed, as in the linked project using spring-boot-starter-parent version 2.4.5 and cucumber-jvm version 6.10.4.

I set the junit-platform properties as follows:

```
cucumber.execution.parallel.enabled=true
cucumber.execution.parallel.config.strategy=fixed
cucumber.execution.parallel.config.fixed.parallelism=4
```

Used annotation `@Cucumber` in the runner class and `@SpringBootTest` for classes with steps definition.

It seems to work fine with creating parallel threads, but the problem is it creates all the threads at the start and opens as many browser windows (drivers) as the number of scenarios (e.g. 51 instead of 4).
[image: Console logs threads]

I am using a `CucumberHooks` class to add logic before and after scenarios and I'm guessing it interferes with the runner because of the annotations I'm using:

```
import java.util.List;
import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import io.cucumber.java.After;
import io.cucumber.java.Before;
import io.cucumber.java.Scenario;
import io.cucumber.plugin.ConcurrentEventListener;
import io.cucumber.plugin.event.EventHandler;
import io.cucumber.plugin.event.EventPublisher;
import io.cucumber.plugin.event.TestRunFinished;
import io.cucumber.plugin.event.TestRunStarted;
import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager;

public class CucumberHooks implements ConcurrentEventListener {

@Autowired
private ScenarioContext scenarioContext;

@Before
public void beforeScenario(Scenario scenario) {
    scenarioContext.getNewDriverInstance();
    scenarioContext.setScenario(scenario);
    LOGGER.info("Driver initialized for scenario - {}", scenario.getName());
    ....
    <some business logic here>
    ....
}

@After
public void afterScenario() {
    Scenario scenario = scenarioContext.getScenario();
    WebDriver driver = scenarioContext.getDriver();

    takeErrorScreenshot(scenario, driver);
    LOGGER.info("Driver will close for scenario - {}", scenario.getName());

    driver.quit();
}

private void takeErrorScreenshot(Scenario scenario, WebDriver driver) {
    if (scenario.isFailed()) {
        final byte[] screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
        scenario.attach(screenshot, "image/png", "Failure");
    }
}

@Override
public void setEventPublisher(EventPublisher eventPublisher) {
    eventPublisher.registerHandlerFor(TestRunStarted.class, beforeAll);
}

private EventHandler<TestRunStarted> beforeAll = event -> {
    // something that needs doing before everything
    .....<some business logic here>....
    WebDriverManager.getInstance(DriverManagerType.CHROME).setup();
};
```

}

I tried replacing the `@Before` tag from `io.cucumber.java` with the `@BeforeEach` from `org.junit.jupiter.api` and it does not work.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: What is `scenarioContext`?

Comment: Did you see 51 web drivers open at once or are you assuming this is the case based on the thread names in the logging?

Comment: `scenarioContext` is an attribute in that class, I had to remove some business related information from the example and I removed that also by mistake. 
I can see the Chrome drivers being opened almost at once. First around 10, then another 10 and in 2 seconds all 50. It's not exactly instant, but I can also see from the thread names that way more than 4 are opened. I would have expected the thread names to go over 4, maybe up to 16-20....but it goes to worker 123.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in your code. You may either have to make your problem smaller by removing everything you don't strictly need to reproduce it. Or put a breakpoint in the CucumberTestEngine class to see what properties are used to create the executor.

Comment: I think I figured out the reason, but I did not yet find a specific solution. The scenarioContext is an attribute of type ScenarioContext (a class that wraps the driver and the Scenario instance), that had the `@Autowired` annotation from Spring. I expected that for each scenario this object was created when the `@Before` method was called, seeing how this method is not static, but I added some logs and saw that it is the same instance each time, and so even though multiple driver instances are created, they remain suspended because only the last one is used in the tests.

Comment: You have to make the scenarioContext scenario scoped. It is currently apolication scoped. All scenarios share the same application. So any scenario state must be in it's own scope. https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/main/spring/README.md#sharing-state-between-steps

Comment: Thank you so much! I was reading about Spring and thread safety to try and find a solution and this worked, now all the drivers are closed properly and half the tests are passing. However, they still open all at once. I have commented out some of the scenarios, now I only have 11 active and they all open at once. I can see it visually, but also from the logs, that before opening any url in any driver, all 11 are opened by the code inside the `@Before` method.

Comment: You'll have to put a breakpoint in `CucumberTestEngine.createExecutorService` and see what happens there.

Comment: I debugged as suggested and saw that all properties were fine and 4 threads were first created. Then in the `@Before` method, the first line will call a method that creates a new `org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver` instance which is kept as an attribute in the scenarioContext. When the new `ChromeDriver` instance is created, a new thread appears. I tried to debug further but I got lost in the http related code. This happens only once when debugging one of the threads, then the rest do not add new threads, the total remains at 5. I assume it's because I followed one thread until the end.

Comment: You can ignore the threads used by the Chrome driver  to talk to Chrome. They're extra threads but aren't involved in running tests. 

Can you remove enough stuff from the project so it's safe to share on Github?

Comment: I added the project here: https://github.com/danieldruga/cucumber-parallel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as it turns out `parallism` is mostly a suggestion. Cucumber uses JUnit5s [`ForkJoinPoolHierarchicalTestExecutorService`](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/blob/a411d71614dc4c99e72683d1709e6655985c85fa/junit-platform-engine/src/main/java/org/junit/platform/engine/support/hierarchical/ForkJoinPoolHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java#L86-L91) which constructs a `ForkJoinPool`.

From the docs on `ForkJoinPool`:

> For applications that require separate or custom pools, a ForkJoinPool may be constructed with a given target parallelism level; by default, equal to the number of available processors. The pool attempts to maintain enough active (or available) threads by dynamically adding, suspending, or resuming internal worker threads, even if some tasks are stalled waiting to join others. However, no such adjustments are guaranteed in the face of blocked I/O or other unmanaged synchronization.

So within a `ForkJoinPool` when ever a thread blocks for example because it starts asynchronous communication with the web driver another thread may be started to maintain the parallelism.

Since all threads wait, more threads are added to the pool and more web drivers are started.

This means that rather then relying on the `ForkJoinPool` to limit the number of webdrivers you have to do this yourself. You can use a library like [Apache Commons Pool](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-pool/) or implement a rudimentary pool using a counting semaphore.

```java
@Component
@ScenarioScope
public class ScenarioContext {

    private static final int MAX_CONCURRENT_WEB_DRIVERS = 1;
    private static final Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(MAX_CONCURRENT_WEB_DRIVERS, true);

    private WebDriver driver;

    public WebDriver getDriver() {
        if (driver != null) {
            return driver;
        }

        try {
            semaphore.acquire();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        try {
            driver = CustomChromeDriver.getInstance();
        } catch (Throwable t){
            semaphore.release();
            throw t;
        }
        return driver;
    }

    public void retireDriver() {
        if (driver == null) {
            return;
        }

        try {
            driver.quit();
        } finally {
            driver = null;
            semaphore.release();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this solution! I implemented a counting semaphore as suggested and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

New answer, JUnit 5 has been improved somewhat.

If you are on Java 9+ you can use the following in `junit-platform.properties` to enable a custom parallelism.

```
cucumber.execution.parallel.enabled=true
cucumber.execution.parallel.config.strategy=custom
cucumber.execution.parallel.config.custom.class=com.example.MyCustomParallelStrategy
```

And you'd implement `MyCustomParallelStrategy` as:

```java
package com.example;

import org.junit.platform.engine.ConfigurationParameters;
import org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ParallelExecutionConfiguration;
import org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ParallelExecutionConfigurationStrategy;

import java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool;
import java.util.function.Predicate;

public class MyCustomParallelStrategy implements ParallelExecutionConfiguration, ParallelExecutionConfigurationStrategy {

    private static final int FIXED_PARALLELISM = 4


    @Override
    public ParallelExecutionConfiguration createConfiguration(final ConfigurationParameters configurationParameters) {
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public Predicate<? super ForkJoinPool> getSaturatePredicate() {
        return (ForkJoinPool p) -> true;
    }

    @Override
    public int getParallelism() {
        return FIXED_PARALLELISM;
    }

    @Override
    public int getMinimumRunnable() {
        return FIXED_PARALLELISM;
    }

    @Override
    public int getMaxPoolSize() {
        return FIXED_PARALLELISM;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCorePoolSize() {
        return FIXED_PARALLELISM;
    }

    @Override
    public int getKeepAliveSeconds() {
        return 30;
    }
```

On Java 9+ this will limit the max-pool size of the underlying forkjoin pool to `FIXED_PARALLELISM` and there should never be more then 8 web drivers active at the same time.

Also once [JUnit5/#3044](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/pull/3044) is merged, released an integrated into Cucumber, you can use the `cucumber.execution.parallel.config.fixed.max-pool-size` on Java 9+ to limit the maximum number of concurrent tests.

Comment: Will try it as soon as an upgrade to Java 9+ is done. Thanks for following up!